# find Socket server in Lan with C#

Tags: c#, sockets, ip

I wrote a **socket** program in **C#**

I tested all solutions and all of them use single IP address for connecting client to server ...

I want do this just like LAN games (client automatically finding servers in LAN )

**how can I do this with C# ?**

Comment: You can use an IP address or a hostname.  If you use a hostname, your computer must be able to resolve that name to an IP address (e.g. using DNS, or /etc/hosts).  Ultimately, the socket is established via IP address, regardless.

Answer (score 2):

salam. For all socket connection you must have 2 parameters:

- **destination server name** (can be **ip address** (IPV4/IPV6) like `127.0.0.1`
  or **host name** like `http://stackoverflow.com`.
- **destination server port number** like: *25*

Answer (score 0):

`Socket.Connect` method does not only take an IP adress to connect a socket to a remote server.

There are many different versions of the `Socket.Connect` method taking different parameters.
One of the version takes a distant hostname and a port to connect the socket to.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7ew360f.aspx for reference.

In any case, to connect to a remote server you will need either the IP address of the server (eg 10.4.5.66) or the hostname (eg google.com)

Comment: When you use host name, it will be resolved into IP address before connection establishing. There is no way to establishing connection without knowing server IP.